# How to mount formula with dynamic sheet name

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I want to mount my formula using the dynamic value at A36 (green at image) , but I don't know even it is possible - dynamic sheet name.

I tried  to use '&' to concat, but not worked

[image]

ps: I didn't found another Stack Community specific to google spreadsheets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `INDIRECT`

```
=INDIRECT(H2&"!A2")
```

Where `H2` is `Sheet2`

*(Please adjust ranges to your needs)*

[image]